# Set Scrollbar position at given line number in CodeMirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror, codemirror-modes, ui-codemirror

I want to set the scrollbar position in codemirror at given line. I am using scrollTo() method like below. But it is not working. Let's say if there are total 100 lines, Initially I want to show user from line 61.

```
editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('cm'), {
              mode: "xml",
              theme: "default",
              lineNumbers: true
          });

editor.scrollTo(null,61);
```

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution :

Use editor.setCursor(lineNumber) instead of scrollTo() method. It's working fine.